# SVN to Git migration question about performing migration in case-insensitive systems (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, svn, migration, git-svn

I have a question about SVN to Git migration. There are some external guides that advise not to perform the migration on a case-insensitive file systems like Windows. For example:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-prepare

"Migrating to Git should be done on a case-sensitive file system to avoid corrupting the repository. "

Has someone done this migration? should I use a Linux system to perform the migration? or is it ok to use git bash on Windows to perform the migration?

Comment: NTFS *is* case-sensitive. I don't know exactly, what the tutorial is warning against, so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Windows does not typically configure NTFS in a case-sensitive way.  If you're using that tool, then follow the recommendations: use a WSL instance or a Linux box.  There may be other tools which don't have that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't read **any** Atlassian docs - they lie (or just *totallly incompetent*)
2. Don't use suggested in this "manual" Atlassian's tool - because with, f.e., [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) you'll have no headache even on complex and hard migration cases

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations but it is not the answer I was looking for....